# Is there a module in go like ansible in python?

Tags: python, go, ansible

When we want to execute some task in remote server in go project, is there some module in go like ansible in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a package called `gosible`: https://github.com/paulczar/gosible. This is a wrapper around Ansible.